# Dotnet open auth with Facebook and Email/Password login with aspnet_membership tables

Tags: oauth, asp.net-membership, dotnetopenauth

I'm building my first mobile app in which users can login. My app talks to webservices on my site's backend.
Users can login/register via either

1. Facebook 
   or
2. an email/password combination

In both cases (upon registration) I add user data to the aspnet_membership tables, in case of a Facebook registration the only extra thing is that I also store the Facebook Id.

Now, I want to use DotNetOpenAuth to facilitate the login and registration process. But obviously I need to alter some code for the logic that creates/retrieves data from aspnet_membership database tables.

Is this possible and if so, does anyone have code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not alter **aspnet_membership** table. If so, underlying store procedures will stop working.

Instead, you want to create a new table with **UserId** as primary key, and make **one-to-one relationship** with aspnet_membership table.

***FYI:*** the ASP .Net Membership Provider you are using is more than 10 years old, and not actively developing anymore.

If you are developing a new project,  you should consider using new [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) which support Facebook Login out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the Identity project and will have a look at it. But you're saying that this supports existing users connecting via oAUth with their existing username/password (stored in the old aspnet_membership tables)? Also do you know if upon migration the current userId is preserved?